# Where to save additional user data after authentification in zend framework 2

Tags: php, session, authentication, zend-framework2

I use Zend_Auth for authentication with the standard session storage (Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session).

Maybe on another request, after the user is authenticated, i have to save some additional information about the user into the session.
I don´t know if it is best practice to use the auth storage for saving additional information of the user into the session like

```
$authSession = new Container('Zend_Auth');
$storage = $authSession->storage;
$storage['additionalUserInfo'] = 'top secret;
```

or is it better to create a complete new Zend\Session\Container for the user session?

Answer (score 1):

A few good practices:

1. Don't interact directly with the storage utilized by your Authentication service. Use the prescribed usage of the service (to check and get your authenticated identity ie: `$authService->getIdentity()`).
2. Don't fall into the trap of segregating your storage into types like "session", "cache", "db". There is only "Storage".
3. Don't entangle authentication, session state and data storage.

   - Authentication doesn't necessarily mean there is a session (think about REST services and OAuth which should be stateless).
   - Access to user data should not need initialization of session (Imagine you have a system process that has to iterate over all your users and perform some action based on session data. Some how you have to bootstrap a session state to get at the data you need--horrible).

You're on the right track to create a new container to store additional data. But I wouldn't classify it as "Session" storage, instead classify it as a data service for whatever it is actually storing. I might do something like this:

```
// define an interface for a data service 
interface UserRepositoryInterface {
    public function setAdditionalInfo($info);
    public function getAdditionalInfo();
}

// this is still bad because it breaks best practice #3
// but it is sufficient for the example and is a good start
class UserContainer implements UserRepositoryInterface {
    // implement methods using Zend\Session\Container
}

// configure service manager to return your data service
'service_manager' => [
    'factory' => [
        'user_container' => function($sm){
            return new UserContainer();
        }
    ]
]
```

Now, to get at your data, somewhere in your code you might do:

```
$data_service = $service_manager->get('user_container');
$additional_info = $data_service->getAdditionalInfo();
```

Later when you need to move storage out of session and into some other storage mechanism like Redis, MySQL, etc (this kind of thing happens when you start scaling your application and you no longer have sticky sessions and for other reasons) you'll have a lot easier go of things. You can write a different adapter, and swap out which adapter is provided by the service manager.

Comment: But i need the information in a session, because the user can do some more request in my application. Should i go for injecting the AuthService into my other Services to get the Storage and then using the `$storage->write()` function? But on my first test this function overrides all Data in the Storage. Or is the AuthStorage realy not for adding data after authentication?

Comment: It's fine if you "need" the information in a session (you don't, there's always an alternative) simply implement the UserContainer described above using Zend\Session\Container as the comment suggests. And no, don't add AuthService to your other services, add UserContainer to your other services. UserContainer provides the access and handles the details of where the data comes from (session wise or other).

Answer (score 0):

I have a special singleton class with static methods to save and retrieve session variables. This is actually a basic container for ZF2 session classes. Copy and paste it:

```
namespace Application\Core;

use Zend\Session\Container;

class Session {

    private static $container;

    private static function getContainer() {
        if (!self::$container) {
            self::$container = new Container('instela');
        }

        return self::$container;
    }

    public static function setValue($key, $value) {
        try {
            self::getContainer()->$key = $value;
        } catch (\Zend\Session\Exception\RuntimeException $e) {

            return false;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function getValue($key) {
        try {
            return self::getContainer()->$key;
        } catch (\Zend\Session\Exception\RuntimeException $e) {
            return false;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

The usage is very simple,

```
Session::setValue('variable',$var);
$var=Session::getValue('variable');
```